# jquery: pick an element by :contains

Tags: jquery

I just tried jquery's `$(':contains foobar');` in my Chrome javascript console. Instead of selecting the element that contains the text "foobar", it just selects the whole page!

How can I  make it select the element containing the text "foobar"?

Comment: `:contains(...)` selects elements whose `.innerText` contains that string. Since `body` contains everything, it will be selected as well, as will every ancestor of the element that actually contains the text as child. You can't change the behavior of the selector, so you have to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(':contains(foobar)')`. Dont forget the ()s.